# Take previous element from array if condition on current element matches

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Any ideas to simplify this beauty; I would prefer a LinQ expression if possible:

```
private object[] array;
public abstract bool Condition(object o);
//...
private object FindStuff()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        if (Condition(array[i]))
        {
            return i == 0 ? null : array[i-1];
        }
    }
    throw new ItemNotFoundException();
}
//...
```

Comment: Using the assumption, that there is an `object foo;` as a non-valid data-placeholder, I have a new approach but I hate it even more:

    `return array.Select((t, i) => Condition(t) ? i == 0 ? null : array[i - 1] : foo).First(e => e != foo);`

Comment: The method signature is incorrect. It should be private **object** FindStuff();

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This code would benefit from a `previous` variable...... and it would also benefit from being *real* code, not this hypothetical example..... This code is also really short, so it's hard to simplify more.

Still, using a foreach is better than the indexed iterator, and the logic is more obvious with named variables, rather than indexes... so:

```
private object[] array;
public abstract bool Condition(object o);
//...
private object FindStuff()
{
    object previous = null;
    foreach (object current in array)
    {
        if (Condition(current))
        {
            return previous;
        }
        previous = current;
    }
    throw new ItemNotFoundException();
}
```

Comment: Just a minor one - you're returning an object from a void method.

Comment: @Coda - thanks for noticing that. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

`List<T>` has `FindIndex(Predicate<T>)` which returns index or -1 when item was not found.

```
private static object FindStuff(List<object> list)
{
    int index = list.FindIndex(Condition);

    if (index < 0) throw new ItemNotFoundException();

    if (index == 0) return null;

    return list[index - 1];
}

private static bool Condition(object o)
{
    return true;
}
```

I don't like returning null, but whateva :)

Comment: Yes that's a nice solution as well ... but I would prefer a switch instead of the if-else. I like the other answer more, since it is working without any magic numbers.

Comment: To be fair I also like rolfl solution more because it tells what you want to do but to be honestly I don't like an idea of creating function like this. How you will use it? :) `try { FindStuff(); DealWithNullCase() } catch { }`?  This function smells very bad... I would probably at least split it in two functions `bool PreviousExists()`, `bool Previous()`.

Comment: You are right the sample is not very good! The snippet above is just an abstraction of my real issue. There is code before and after the loop and the method name is also different. My method is also not returning null, but a default value coming from the method's params.

However, I'd have to explain a whole tree data structure concept to post the original method here ...

Comment: `else` is not needed if the previous `if` statement ends with a `return` or `throw`. Also you should handle exceptional cases, such as negative return value from `FindIndex`, as close to the relevant location as possible. Also @Markus: [0 and 1 are not magical numbers](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ZeroOneInfinityRule).

Comment: Yes but `-1` is ;)

I've tested your code with a `switch(index) {case -1: throw new Exception(); case 0: return null; default: return list[index-1];}`

Answer (score 3):

The question seems to be missing an important constraint in case there are repeating elements in the input collection that satisfy the condition given. Therefore, there is an assumption around the solutions provided that we are interested in the **first encounter only**.

How about a more general approach to return an IEnumerable collection so that the caller can decide what to take out of that such as the first, the last or the nth, etc.

```
    private static IEnumerable<object> Find(object[] array)
    {
        if (array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));

        object previous = null;
        foreach (var current in array)
        {
            if (Predicate(current)) yield return previous;

            previous = current;
        }
    }

    private static bool Predicate(object o)
    {
        return o != null && (int)o == 2;
    }
```

There is also a null check for the input to fail fast. Predicate logic is irrelevant here.

Following is the test cases for the Find method:

```
    [Test]
    public void TestFind()
    {
        var items = Find(new object[] { 1, 2, 5, 2, 10, 2, 100, 2 });
        Assert.AreEqual(1, items.First());

        items = Find(new object[] { 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 });
        Assert.IsEmpty(items);

        Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => Find(null).ToList());
    }
```